# Need help isolating results from xhr request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

When I run the code below, it's giving me a lot of information I don't want.  I only want to capture the data circled starting with 4. Does anyone know how to isolate the data in the request to get rid of everything but what is circled?  Also, if anyone knows how to bring the results to a csv or xlsx file, that would be even better.

[image: XHR Request]

Working code:

```
   import requests

url = "https://www.stockrover.com/stock_infos/grid?_dc=1644769629231"
```

data = {
"ticker": 4,
"rank": "5",
}

```
payload = "state=%7B%22sortInfo%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B77%2C32%2C498%2C500%2C31%2C27%2C499%2C30%2C578%2C28%2C29%2C544%2C181%2C185%2C186%5D%2C%22view%22%3A281%2C%22priorPrimaryColumn%22%3A170%2C%22filterData%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22name%22%3A%22New%201%22%2C%22cType%22%3A%22Screener%22%2C%22cNode%22%3A%22s_39%22%2C%22cIsFolder%22%3Afalse%2C%22gridSelection%22%3A%22BTU%22%2C%22lastActive%22%3A1396898415%2C%22primaryColumn%22%3A76%2C%22folderDisabledParams%22%3A%7B%22filterData%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22mainGridDateRange%22%3A%22ytd%22%2C%22groupState%22%3Anull%2C%22moversGridDateRange%22%3A%221_day%22%2C%22peersGridDateRange%22%3A%221_day%22%2C%22lastGridSelections%22%3A%5B%22BTU%22%5D%2C%22lastQuantNode%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22includeQuotesInTable%22%3Afalse%2C%22includeAllQuotesLastValue%22%3Afalse%2C%22markets%22%3A%7B%22panel%22%3A%22summary%22%7D%2C%22researchPanel%22%3A%22tablePanel%22%2C%22recentSearchTickers%22%3A%5B%22SPY%22%2C%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22s_32%22%2C%22%5ENDX%22%2C%22AXP%22%2C%22XOM%22%2C%22AFL%22%2C%22%5EDJX%22%2C%22AIT%22%2C%22ADVC%22%5D%2C%22quotesBoxTickers%22%3A%5B%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22SPY%22%5D%2C%22checkedQuotesBoxTickers%22%3A%5B%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22SPY%22%5D%2C%22dashboard%22%3A%7B%22buttonRef%22%3A%22272%22%7D%2C%22tickerSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Benzinga%20News%22%2C%22Yahoo%20News%22%5D%2C%22marketSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Stock%20Market%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22bondsSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Bonds%20Strategy%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22commoditiesSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Commodities%20%26%20Futures%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Commodities%20Fundamental%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Commodities%20Strategy%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22stocksSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22CNNMoney%20News%22%2C%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Seeking%20Alpha%20Top%20Stories%22%5D%2C%22etfsSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Economy%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22ETF%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Investing%20Ideas%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22topPanel%22%3A%22researchPanel%22%2C%22maxRecordsNode%22%3Afalse%2C%22version%22%3A7%2C%22lastGridSelectionsRaw%22%3A%5B%22BTU%22%5D%2C%22lastSelectionScreeners%22%3A%22s_39%22%2C%22quotesDisabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22lastSelectionPortfolios%22%3A%22p_2%22%2C%22comparisonPanels%22%3A%7B%22Portfolio%22%3A%22p_2%22%2C%22Index%22%3A%22%5EDJX%22%2C%22Watchlist%22%3A%22Watchlists%22%2C%22Screener%22%3A%22s_39%22%7D%2C%22lastSelectionWatchlists%22%3A%22w_26%22%2C%22indicesSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Yahoo%20News%22%5D%2C%22newsActive%22%3A%22tickerNews%22%2C%22recentSearchMetrics%22%3A%5B%22Price%22%2C%22EPS%22%2C%22Sales%22%5D%2C%22editPanel%22%3A%22positionsPanel%22%2C%22newsType%22%3A%22marketNews%22%2C%22tableColumns%22%3A%5B%22ticker%22%2C%22rank%22%2C%22score_rank%22%2C%22filter_score%22%2C%22company%22%2C%22cash%22%2C%22currentassets%22%2C%22netppe%22%2C%22intangibles%22%2C%22totalassets%22%2C%22currentliabilities%22%2C%22longtermdebt%22%2C%22totaldebt%22%2C%22totalliabilities%22%2C%22equity%22%2C%22tangiblebookvalue%22%2C%22cash_short_term_p%22%2C%22net_ppe_p%22%2C%22intangibles_p%22%5D%2C%22last_save%22%3A1644769379%2C%22panels%22%3A%7B%22collapsed%22%3A%7B%22chp%22%3Atrue%2C%22ip%22%3Atrue%2C%22mp%22%3Afalse%2C%22qp%22%3Afalse%2C%22conp%22%3Atrue%2C%22fsp%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22viewportWidth%22%3A%221920%22%2C%22viewportHeight%22%3A%221069%22%2C%22chartPanelHeight%22%3A483%2C%22controlPanelWidth%22%3A296%2C%22insightPanelWidth%22%3A%22485%22%2C%22quoteBoxHeight%22%3A200%2C%22navigationPanelWidth%22%3A277%7D%7D&updateMarket=true&page=1&start=0&limit=250"
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.stockrover.com',
  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
  'x-csrf-token': '7yR4pfI0kAArtjJak535+NJrpB0L212PAbXCg0kbyE4SyjFaQ73sMHJLiqAkPb5nGzfC8KvAa3kTADLAEQXyOQ==',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'accept': 'application/json',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'origin': 'https://www.stockrover.com',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'referer': 'https://www.stockrover.com/research/table/281/s_39/BTU',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'cookie': 'remember_me_pref=0; user_name=test11964; plan=3; premiumBraintreeKey=MIIBCgKCAQEAzM4LJfrNnBOgRFB1dDJkmqTFCWT2Y%2BksOydD8xDH4R033WUzxbffMZb%2B3dqEyQvOVjLcwFIHByDc4Xwej7enas2E%2FVRyh7Cvyadn7M5zQeRyLcI9Ys5KCozMwxJPc0x76FlXPwiAo1Qlz3RcLb9wGHBag2R51FuTie%2BhVDCgzWajqDCREzRhi%2Fqlt3D%2FxXNo%2FiwJlpOUr%2Fx1QnkkILxgKlq1dD7KJ767O5ojYKXsO%2BV2Bfu7sSD3djsOxQJ1%2FRbaDm2E96EDkWhhOeOpPndQ6IuSl4NmnJg%2Fcq6f8csW8M3Ys%2BMZPFkdxPC4%2FfRM1XC9o76PjpVNBIO%2ByJEELKZedwIDAQAB; lr=1644769628; _Ruby2_session=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%3D--1439f36a7f9362aee4b5b666747a2d63d72e81bd'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.json())
```

[image: Table]

Comment: If you acquire *response.json()* you will have a normal Python dictionary that you can navigate in whichever way suits you

Comment: Added that line but doesn't seem much different than what I had with text?

Comment: That's because you have to write code to get the data you want out of the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure in this case is rather unusual but this looks like it might work for you:

```
import requests
    
url = "https://www.stockrover.com/stock_infos/grid?_dc=1644769629231"

payload = "state=%7B%22sortInfo%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B77%2C32%2C498%2C500%2C31%2C27%2C499%2C30%2C578%2C28%2C29%2C544%2C181%2C185%2C186%5D%2C%22view%22%3A281%2C%22priorPrimaryColumn%22%3A170%2C%22filterData%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22name%22%3A%22New%201%22%2C%22cType%22%3A%22Screener%22%2C%22cNode%22%3A%22s_39%22%2C%22cIsFolder%22%3Afalse%2C%22gridSelection%22%3A%22BTU%22%2C%22lastActive%22%3A1396898415%2C%22primaryColumn%22%3A76%2C%22folderDisabledParams%22%3A%7B%22filterData%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22mainGridDateRange%22%3A%22ytd%22%2C%22groupState%22%3Anull%2C%22moversGridDateRange%22%3A%221_day%22%2C%22peersGridDateRange%22%3A%221_day%22%2C%22lastGridSelections%22%3A%5B%22BTU%22%5D%2C%22lastQuantNode%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22includeQuotesInTable%22%3Afalse%2C%22includeAllQuotesLastValue%22%3Afalse%2C%22markets%22%3A%7B%22panel%22%3A%22summary%22%7D%2C%22researchPanel%22%3A%22tablePanel%22%2C%22recentSearchTickers%22%3A%5B%22SPY%22%2C%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22s_32%22%2C%22%5ENDX%22%2C%22AXP%22%2C%22XOM%22%2C%22AFL%22%2C%22%5EDJX%22%2C%22AIT%22%2C%22ADVC%22%5D%2C%22quotesBoxTickers%22%3A%5B%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22SPY%22%5D%2C%22checkedQuotesBoxTickers%22%3A%5B%22AMZN%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22SPY%22%5D%2C%22dashboard%22%3A%7B%22buttonRef%22%3A%22272%22%7D%2C%22tickerSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Benzinga%20News%22%2C%22Yahoo%20News%22%5D%2C%22marketSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Stock%20Market%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22bondsSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Bonds%20Strategy%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22commoditiesSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Commodities%20%26%20Futures%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Commodities%20Fundamental%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Commodities%20Strategy%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22stocksSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22CNNMoney%20News%22%2C%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Seeking%20Alpha%20Top%20Stories%22%5D%2C%22etfsSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Economy%20News%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22ETF%20Analysis%20-%20Investing.com%22%2C%22Investing%20Ideas%20-%20Investing.com%22%5D%2C%22topPanel%22%3A%22researchPanel%22%2C%22maxRecordsNode%22%3Afalse%2C%22version%22%3A7%2C%22lastGridSelectionsRaw%22%3A%5B%22BTU%22%5D%2C%22lastSelectionScreeners%22%3A%22s_39%22%2C%22quotesDisabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22lastSelectionPortfolios%22%3A%22p_2%22%2C%22comparisonPanels%22%3A%7B%22Portfolio%22%3A%22p_2%22%2C%22Index%22%3A%22%5EDJX%22%2C%22Watchlist%22%3A%22Watchlists%22%2C%22Screener%22%3A%22s_39%22%7D%2C%22lastSelectionWatchlists%22%3A%22w_26%22%2C%22indicesSelectedFeeds%22%3A%5B%22Google%20News%22%2C%22Yahoo%20News%22%5D%2C%22newsActive%22%3A%22tickerNews%22%2C%22recentSearchMetrics%22%3A%5B%22Price%22%2C%22EPS%22%2C%22Sales%22%5D%2C%22editPanel%22%3A%22positionsPanel%22%2C%22newsType%22%3A%22marketNews%22%2C%22tableColumns%22%3A%5B%22ticker%22%2C%22rank%22%2C%22score_rank%22%2C%22filter_score%22%2C%22company%22%2C%22cash%22%2C%22currentassets%22%2C%22netppe%22%2C%22intangibles%22%2C%22totalassets%22%2C%22currentliabilities%22%2C%22longtermdebt%22%2C%22totaldebt%22%2C%22totalliabilities%22%2C%22equity%22%2C%22tangiblebookvalue%22%2C%22cash_short_term_p%22%2C%22net_ppe_p%22%2C%22intangibles_p%22%5D%2C%22last_save%22%3A1644769379%2C%22panels%22%3A%7B%22collapsed%22%3A%7B%22chp%22%3Atrue%2C%22ip%22%3Atrue%2C%22mp%22%3Afalse%2C%22qp%22%3Afalse%2C%22conp%22%3Atrue%2C%22fsp%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22viewportWidth%22%3A%221920%22%2C%22viewportHeight%22%3A%221069%22%2C%22chartPanelHeight%22%3A483%2C%22controlPanelWidth%22%3A296%2C%22insightPanelWidth%22%3A%22485%22%2C%22quoteBoxHeight%22%3A200%2C%22navigationPanelWidth%22%3A277%7D%7D&updateMarket=true&page=1&start=0&limit=250"
headers = {
    'authority': 'www.stockrover.com',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
    'x-csrf-token': '7yR4pfI0kAArtjJak535+NJrpB0L212PAbXCg0kbyE4SyjFaQ73sMHJLiqAkPb5nGzfC8KvAa3kTADLAEQXyOQ==',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'origin': 'https://www.stockrover.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.stockrover.com/research/table/281/s_39/BTU',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'remember_me_pref=0; user_name=test11964; plan=3; premiumBraintreeKey=MIIBCgKCAQEAzM4LJfrNnBOgRFB1dDJkmqTFCWT2Y%2BksOydD8xDH4R033WUzxbffMZb%2B3dqEyQvOVjLcwFIHByDc4Xwej7enas2E%2FVRyh7Cvyadn7M5zQeRyLcI9Ys5KCozMwxJPc0x76FlXPwiAo1Qlz3RcLb9wGHBag2R51FuTie%2BhVDCgzWajqDCREzRhi%2Fqlt3D%2FxXNo%2FiwJlpOUr%2Fx1QnkkILxgKlq1dD7KJ767O5ojYKXsO%2BV2Bfu7sSD3djsOxQJ1%2FRbaDm2E96EDkWhhOeOpPndQ6IuSl4NmnJg%2Fcq6f8csW8M3Ys%2BMZPFkdxPC4%2FfRM1XC9o76PjpVNBIO%2ByJEELKZedwIDAQAB; lr=1644769628; _Ruby2_session=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%3D--1439f36a7f9362aee4b5b666747a2d63d72e81bd'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

stock_info = response.json()['stock_infos']

for info in stock_info:
    key = info[0]
    for i, sub in enumerate(info[1:], 1):
        if sub == key:
            print(info[i:])
            break
```

**Output:**

```
['AA', 1452.0, 4285.0, 6679.0, 0.0, 14197.0, 2929.0, 1724.0, 1725.0, 8736.0, 3878.0, 3878.0, 10.23, 47.05, None]
['ACH', 1773.84, 7909.0, 18758.17, 788.41, 30523.38, 9252.6, 8782.1, 14242.28, 18580.33, 9038.55, 8250.17, 5.81, 61.46, 2.58]
```

...and the values for all observed tickers

Comment: Is there anyway around hardcoding the symbols and having them come from the table instead?

Comment: Do you mean a database table? If so then yes there is a way

Comment: Yes, the xhr request makes an internet table.  I put a snip of it at the bottom of my post. Let me know if I can provide you any information to help.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Try it